# Buffer overflow doesn't work when the payload changes

Tags: ctf

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9dY6.png)

I'm doing picoctf Buffer Overflow1 and notice that for some reason, the added 4 bytes to do overflow does not work when the bytes are beyond a certain size. When I changed the xfe to x05, the jumping address was changed to the injected one. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Tried to find help in google and youtube but nothing came up.